# Showing loader inside a dialog popup

Tags: sapui5

I have made a page in UI5 in which there is a button to open the dialog popup. On this popup page, I have some text boxes and chart, but the chart is taking so much time in loading so the entire page is displayed as white screen until the chart is loaded.

I want to show some loader for this white screen. What can be the possible solution?

(I was trying for loading a text box first and then chart but the problem is entire page is loaded together)

Comment: You will use SAPUI5 loading for it. It has available on SAPUI5 sdk.

Comment: use Busy Indicator on your "dialog-control" via var oDialog = '.....'; and then use oDialog.setBusy(true); ... and at the end of loading setBusy(false)... hope this helps

Comment: that is what the problem..whole page is getting loaded alltogether

Answer (score -1):

try below code for loader.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
    <head>  
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>Example Application</title>  
        <script id="util-coreloader"  
                src="util/CoreLoader.js"  
                data-loader-src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"  
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"  
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"  
                data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{  
                        "com.inwerken": "../com_inwerken"  
                }'  
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">  
        </script>  
        <script>  
        // execute when Core is loaded ...  
        CoreLoader.onReadyState(function() {  
                sap.ui.getCore().attachInitEvent(function () {  
                        // .. load Component  
                        var oComponentContainer = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({  
                                height: "100%",  
                                name: "Example"  
                        });  
                        oComponentContainer.placeAt("content");  
                        CoreLoader.ready();  
                });  
        });  
        </script>  
</head>  
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">  
        <div id="content"></div>  
</body>  
</html>
```